# Querying Excel sheet, find out if rs is empty

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I wrote the proc below, and it's working fine, except that I would like to check if the recordset is empty or not. However, `rs.EoF` and `rs.BoF` always return `False`, even if there is no data. What is the trick to make this work ?

```
Sub PrepData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String, recs As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'create connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

    'check trades without matching couterparty
    strSql = "select distinct tf.counterPart from [TradeFile$A3:G5000] tf " & _
             "left join [CounterpartiesMapping$] c on tf.counterpart = c.counterpart " & _
             "where c.investee is null"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql, recs)

    'HERE I'd like to see if the recordset is empty,
    'but rs.eof and rs.bof are always FALSE regardless of the result
    Debug.Print rs.BOF, rs.EOF, rs.RecordCount
    ws.Range("p3").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close

    cn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html):
Just replace

```
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql, recs)
```

By

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Connection
rs.CursorLocation = adUseCLient
rs.Open strSql, cn
```

Now `Debug.Print rs.BOF, rs.EOF, rs.RecordCount` works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [RecordCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado) property for the recordset to find the number of rows returned?

```
 Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
```

Comment: I did. It always returns -1, wether there are records or not.